# do I need AppCompatActivity & v7 Support Libraries with minimum sdk 21?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I am new to Android and a little bit confused right now.

After setting up a new project with min sdk 21 (Android 5.0) in android studio, by default my `main_activity` extends `AppCompatActivity` which at first was no problem. 
I tried to set up the Material. Dark theme like shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) but `@android:style/Theme.Material` does not work with `AppCompatActivity`.
It works now when `main_activity` just extends `Activity`.

Do I need `AppCompatActivity` with min sdk 21 if I want to use features like `Action Bar`or is it ok to just extend from `Activity`, I thought that `AppCompatActivity` & `v7 Support Libraries` is there to support lower sdk versions to be able to use Material Design, what am I missing ?

If `AppCompatActivity` is not needed in sdk level 21 and up why would android studio set it as default even if 21 is set as min sdk ?

I guess one main question I have is, what is the best practice for using the Material design Theme like explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) combined with AppCompatActivity which Android Studio uses by default.

Comment: Can you select an answer?

Comment: It only is partially answered, I am still unsure about the best practice here. And since i want to be on the save side I decided to stick with Appcompat and stop finding answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use app compat libraries and fragments.

There are bugfixes that get bundled in the support libraries. This way Google can fix a bug in Android without having to wait for people to update their phones.

It is best practice to use the support libraries, including AppCompat and FragmentCompat

With regards to themes, your themes should look like this

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">`

see this https://medium.com/google-developers/theming-with-appcompat-1a292b754b35#.988b91sl1

Answer (score 0):

No but there are some nice views in the `design` support library and `support-v4` that you might want.

**Design:**

- NavigationView

**Support-v4:**

- DrawerLayout

And if you are going this route and want to use "normal" `Fragments` and a `ViewPager`, you need to use `support-v13`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I definitely want a navigation-drawer/NavigationView ? But shouldn't that be possible to use in api 21(5.0) natively without using AppCompat ?  I am also still very unsure about what the best practice is for using '@android:style/Theme.Material' because it does not work with 'AppCompat' since that is the main thing I want.

Comment: Yes, it does not need `AppCompat` it needs the `design` library. `NavigationView` is in the `design` library.

Answer (score 0):

Support libraries are necessary if you want to provide newer's SDKs functionality to older platforms. If your minSDK=5 then you need support libraries only if they contain something that is not included in 5's android SDK

Comment: Thank you, to clarify I am using  minimum SDK API 21(Lollipop), but still android studio extends the main_Activity from AppCompatActivity by default which strangely is not compatible with the Material Design theme which was introduced in API 21. I am just trying to figure out what is best practice or how to use the material theme in the right way.